# Custom metric for NearestNeighbors sklearn

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, nearest-neighbor

Hello I'm on a project where I use 512 bits hash to create clusters. I'm using a custom metric bitwise hamming distance. But when I compare two hash with this function I obtain different distance results than using the NearestNeighbors.

Extending this to DBSCAN, using a eps=5, the cluster are created with some consistence, are being correctly clustered. But I try to check the distance between points from the same cluster I obtain distance enormous. Here is an example.

Example:
This a list of points from 2 clusters created by DBSCAN, and as you can see when using the function to calculate the distance gives number bigger than 30 but the NN gives results consistent with the eps=5.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
hash_list_1 = [2711636196460699638441853508983975450613573844625556129377064665736210167114069990407028214648954985399518205946842968661290371575620508000646896480583712,
             2711636396252606881895803338309150146134565539796776390549907030396205082681800682439355456735713892762967881436259141637319066484744271299497977370896760,
             2711636396252606881918517135048330084905033589325484952567856239496981859330884970846906663264518266744879431357749780779892124020350824669153434630258784,
             2711636396252797418317524490088561493800258861799581574018898781319096107333812163580085003775074676924785748114206505865657620572909617106316367216148512,
             2711636196460318585955127494483972276879239064090689852809978361705086216958169367104329622890567955158961917611852516176654399246340379120409329566384160,
             2711636396252606881918605860499354102197401318666579124151729671752374458560929422237113300739169875232495266727513833203360007861082211711747836501459040,
             2685449071597530523833230885351500532369477539914318172159429043161052628696351016818586542171509728747070238075233795777242761861490021015910382103951968,
             2685449271584547381638295372872027557715092296493457397817270817010861872186702795218797216694169625716749654321460983923962566367029011600112932108533792,
             2685449071792640184514638654713547133316375160837810451952682241651988724244365461216285304336254942220323815140042850082680124299635209323646382761738272,
             1847461275963134712629870519594779049860430827711272857522520377357653173694038204556169999876899727026751811340128091158803029889914422883922033917198368,
             2711636396252606881901567718540735842607739343712295416931961674938924754114357607352250040524848697769853213132484145241805622979375000168935113673834592,
             2711636396252606881901567718538101947732706353297593371282460773094032493492652041376662823635245997887100968237677157520342076957158825588198798784364576]
hash_list_2 = [1677246762479319235863065539858628614044010438213592493389244703420353559152336301659250128835190166728647823546464421558167523127086351613289685036466208,
               1677246762479700308655934218233084077989052614799077817712715603728397519829375248244181345837838956827991047769168833176865438232999821278031784406056992,
               1677246762479700314487411751526941880161990070273187005125752885368412445003620183982282356578440274746789782460884881633682918768578649732794162647826464,
               1677246762479319238759152196394352786642547660315097253847095508872934279466872914748604884925141826161428241625796765725368284151706959618924400925900832,
               1677246762479890853811162999308711253291696853123890392766127782305403145675433285374478727414572392743118524142664546768046227747593095585347134902140960,
               1677246765601448867710925237522621090876591539557992237656925108430781026329148912958069241932475038282622646533152559554888274158032061637714105308528752,
               1678883457783648388335228538833424204662395277995143067623864457726472665342252064374635323999849241968448535982901839797440478656657327613912450890367008,
               1677246765601448864793634462245189770642489500950753120409198344054454862566173176691699195659218600616315451200851360013275424257209428603245704937128032,
               1677246762479700314471974894075267160937462491405299015541470373650765401692659096424270522124311243007780041455682577230603077926878181390448030335795232,
               1677246762479700317400446530288778920091525622772690226165317385340164047644547471081180880454458397836230795248631079659291423401151022423365062554976288,
               1677246762479700317400446530288758590086745084806873060513679821541689120894219120403259478342385343805541797540566045409406476458247878183422733877936160,
               2516871453405060707064684111867902766968378200849671168835363528433280949578746081906100803610196553501646503982070255639855643685380535999494563083255776,
               1677246762479319230037086118512223039643232176451879100417048497454912234466993748113993020733268935613563596294183318283010061477487433484794582123053088,
               1677246762479319235834673272207747972667132521699112379991979781620810490520617303678451683578338921267417975279632387450778387555221361833006151849902112,
               1677246762479700305748490595643272813492272250002832996415474372704463760357437926852625171223210803220593114114602433734175731538424778624130491225112608]


def custom_metric(x, y):
    return bin(int(x[0]) ^ int(y[0])).count('1')


objective_hash = hash_list_1[0]

complete_list = hash_list_1 + hash_list_2

distance = [custom_metric([objective_hash], [hash_point]) for hash_point in complete_list]
print("Function iteration distance:")
print(distance)


neighbors_model = NearestNeighbors(radius=100, algorithm='ball_tree',
                                   leaf_size=2,
                                   metric=custom_metric,
                                   metric_params=None,
                                   n_jobs=4)

X = [[x] for x in complete_list]
neighbors_model.fit(X)
distance, neighborhoods = neighbors_model.radius_neighbors(objective_hash, 100, return_distance=True)
print("Nearest Neighbors distance:")
print(distance)
print("Nearest Neighbors index:")
print(neighborhoods)
```

Comment: Check for any unexpected data conversions. For example, maybe all your data gets converted into doubles?

Comment: Performance wise, your distance function is horrible. Counting chars in a string. Ouch. I suggest you work with the actual bitsy and rewrite this part in cython inside sklearn, to get decent performance.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse as you suggested the problem is that numpy can't handle int that big numerically, and converts to float.
I know it's not really efficient but for now I'm interested in make it work correctly and then comes the optimisation. 

I solved the problem precomputing the distances.

Comment: You probably should use byte arrays... And use efficient bit operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem:

Numpy can't handle numbers so big and converts them to float losing a lot of precision.

The solution:

Precompute with your custom metric all the distances and feed them to the DBSCAN algorithm.